# Magento URL Rewrite rule in htaccess

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

I am doing a project in magento, i just wanted to rewrite the URL for landing page.

For example:

http://release.contus.us/services/SVEP1663/airhotels/property/country/?country=Vietnam
this is my current url , i just wanted to make it as

http://release.contus.us/services/SVEP1663/Vietnam.
How can i do this i referred many site but i didn't get what i expected.

Note: Country is added dynamically by the user at the back end. Waiting for your answers thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

This answer may help you. BUt you need to try variations according to your need. -->> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28884331/4404623

Comment: Hi @vishwas is there any other way to rewrite in .htaccess file. http://release.contus.us/services/SVEP1663/airhotels/property/country/?country=Vietnam  to http://release.contus.us/services/SVEP1663/Vietnam

Comment: I think for that you need to experiment with RewriteRule in .htaccess. According to me only URL Redirection works. Try this code -->
RewriteRule ^OLD-URL-TO-REDIRECT?$ NEW-URL-WHERE-YOU-WANT-TO-REDIRECT-THE-OLD-ONE [R=301,L]  This might help --> http://www.mcnab.co/blog/e-commerce/magento/magneto-htaccess-cms-to-custom-url/